# Creating SSL Certificate files for Jira

Tags: ssl-certificate, godaddy, jira, confluence

I am trying to create the relevant files for my certificate so I can set up Jira and Confluence to use `jira.mydomain.com`/`confluence.mydomain.com` and work over SSL, using Apache. I was following this guide: https://comtronic.com.au/how-to-enable-ssl-on-jira-software-centos-7/

I currently have the following files:

- `domain.crt`
- `domain.pfx`
- `gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b` (I think this is only for Windows?)

I think I need a `.key` file though and I'm unsure how to generate it

The certificate is from GoDaddy, if that helps. I'm using CentOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache as a reverse proxy for Jira then you just have to add your certificates on a path where apache have access to and publish them threw those directives:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
```

Your "domain.crt" seems to be in PEM-Format like the apache ssl certificates and keys should be. The keyfile is created when somebody does generate the CSR (certificate signing request) Veryg good source for all the steps that should be done in detail could be read here: 
[good Documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04)